# mysql: Error 1022 duplicate key in table

Tags: mysql

```
CREATE TABLE `d_s_rep` ( 
`id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, 
`p_id` bigint(20) NOT NULL, 
`i_id` bigint(20) NOT NULL, 
`d_id` bigint(20) NOT NULL, 
`s_id` bigint(20) NOT NULL, 
`t_id` bigint(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0', 
`as_id` bigint(20) NOT NULL, 
`ccount` bigint(20) DEFAULT '0', 
`dcount` bigint(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0', 
`icount` bigint(20) DEFAULT '0', 
`di` bigint(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0', 
`dhi` bigint(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0', 
`r` decimal(25,8) DEFAULT '0.00000000', 
`f_date` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00', 
`t_date` datetime DEFAULT NULL, 
`t_stamp` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, 
PRIMARY KEY (`id`,`f_date`), 
KEY `d_id` (`d_id`), 
KEY `p_id` (`p_id`), 
KEY `f_date` (`f_date`), 
KEY `i_id` (`i_id`), 
KEY `s_id` (`s_id`), 
KEY `t_id` (`t_id`), 
KEY `as_id` (`as_id`) 
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=11064336 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 /*!50100 PARTITION BY RANGE (TO_DAYS(f_date)) (PARTITION p2009OLD VALUES LESS THAN (733863) ENGINE = InnoDB, PARTITION p2009Q2 VALUES LESS THAN (733954) ENGINE = InnoDB, PARTITION p2009Q3 VALUES LESS THAN (734046) ENGINE = InnoDB, PARTITION p2009Q4 VALUES LESS THAN (734138) ENGINE = InnoDB, PARTITION p2010Q1 VALUES LESS THAN (734228) ENGINE = InnoDB, PARTITION p2010Q2 VALUES LESS THAN (734319) ENGINE = InnoDB, PARTITION p2010Q3 VALUES LESS THAN (734411) ENGINE = InnoDB, PARTITION p2010M10 VALUES LESS THAN (734442) ENGINE = InnoDB, PARTITION p2010M11 VALUES LESS THAN (734472) ENGINE = InnoDB, PARTITION p2010M12 VALUES LESS THAN (734503) ENGINE = InnoDB, PARTITION p2011M01 VALUES LESS THAN (734534) ENGINE = InnoDB, PARTITION p2011M02 VALUES LESS THAN (734562) ENGINE = InnoDB, PARTITION p2011M03 VALUES LESS THAN (734593) ENGINE = InnoDB, PARTITION p2011M04 VALUES LESS THAN (734623) ENGINE = InnoDB, PARTITION p2011M05 VALUES LESS THAN (734654) ENGINE = InnoDB, PARTITION p2011M06 VALUES LESS THAN (734684) ENGINE = InnoDB, PARTITION p2011M07 VALUES LESS THAN (734715) ENGINE = InnoDB, PARTITION p2011M08 VALUES LESS THAN (734746) ENGINE = InnoDB, PARTITION p2011M09 VALUES LESS THAN (734776) ENGINE = InnoDB, PARTITION p2011M10 VALUES LESS THAN (734807) ENGINE = InnoDB, PARTITION p2011M11 VALUES LESS THAN (734837) ENGINE = InnoDB, PARTITION p2011M12 VALUES LESS THAN (735173) ENGINE = InnoDB)
```

In above mentioned table few inserts fronm insert query in code fails with error

```
Total Number of diagnostic records: 1 
SQLSTATE: 23000 
Native Error Code: 1022 
[MySQL][ODBC 3.51 Driver][mysqld-5.1.30-community-log]Can't write; duplicate key in table 'd_s_rep'
```

insert statment "does not" include values for id (`NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT`) and t_stamp (`NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`).

I read posts on various forums but could not get the root case for the problem.

It would be great help if some one could guide me to resolve problem

Comment: It looks fine to me, if your query doesn't include id (as you say) it should always be unique. Are you running replication with writes on both machines?

Comment: Thanks for reply. Sorry I did not get your question. FYI Table in whihc I am getting this error gets replicated to backup system

Answer (score 3):

It looks like you're trying to set more than one PRIMARY KEY

```
 PRIMARY KEY (id,f_date)
```

You can only have one PRIMARY KEY and you've already f_date set as a KEY, so just erase **,f_date** and you should be fine.

Comment: Hmm, no... there is a difference between KEY and PRIMARY KEY. There is only one PRIMARY KEY here.

Comment: thanks for reply. f_date is need to be part of PRIMARY KEY as per mysql " All columns used in the partitioning expression for a partitioned table must be part of every unique key that the table may have". Source: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/partitioning-limitations-partitioning-keys-unique-keys.html

Answer (score 0):

You can have it like below; don't declare 'f_date' as key separately

```
PRIMARY KEY (`id`,`f_date`),
  KEY `d_id` (`d_id`),
  KEY `p_id` (`p_id`), 
  KEY `i_id` (`i_id`),
  KEY `s_id` (`s_id`),
  KEY `t_id` (`t_id`),
  KEY `as_id` (`as_id`)
```

Comment: Thanks for reply. 'f_date' as key is required to have index on 'f_date' for queries that select data based on f_date. 'f_date' is needed in PRIMARY KEY as partitioning is based on 'f_date'